# Excluding cells from imputation with mice

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

I am trying to run mice while excluding (not imputed and not imputers) some cases (responses for 6 particular items (colums), for a particular group (1 country))? Is it possible to do this? Would anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

A.

I tried to change the matrix but this doesn't work as I want to exclude some cases, not columns.

Comment: Can you make your post reproducible? You can use the `nhanes` data built into the `mice` package. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I created a small reproducible example and assumed that your `country` variable (ie your grouping variable) contains no `NA` values.

You can use the [`where`](https://amices.org/mice/reference/make.where.html) argument that is part of the `mice` function to specify where you do and don't want values to be imputed. You just need to create a dataframe of logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) to specify where imputations should occur. You can use some `dplyr` manuiplation to make a copy of your dataframe where all values for the `UK` rows are `FALSE`, but everything else is `TRUE`.

```
library(faux) # to generate data
library(missMethods) # to make data missing
library(mice) # to impute
library(dplyr) # for pipes, mutate, and case_when

df <- 
  faux::rnorm_multi(n = 100, vars = 6, mu = 3, sd = 1, 
                        varnames = c("var1", "var2", "var3",
                                     "var4", "var5", "var6")) %>%
  mutate(country = sample(x = c("US", "UK", "FR", "CA", "JP"),
                          size = 100, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  missMethods::delete_MCAR(cols = c("var1", "var2", "var3",
                                   "var4", "var5", "var6"), p = .15)

# make a logical vector to say where you do and
# don't want imputing to occur
here <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(var1:var6), 
                ~ case_when(country == "UK" ~ FALSE,
                            country != "UK" ~ TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(country = FALSE)
head(here)
#>    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 country
#> 1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   FALSE
#> 2  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   FALSE
#> 3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   FALSE
#> 4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   FALSE
#> 5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE
#> 6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE

# use the where argument
imp <- mice(df,
            maxit = 5,
            where = here,
            printFlag = FALSE)
#> Warning: Number of logged events: 1

# proof that uk rows still have some NAs
com <- complete(imp, action = "long", include = FALSE)
com %>%
  filter(country == "UK") %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.))))
#>   .imp .id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 country
#> 1    0   0   15   30   25   20   20   30       0

# proof that all the other countries dont have any NAs
com %>%
  filter(country != "UK") %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.))))
#>   .imp .id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 country
#> 1    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0       0
```

Comment: Thank you!
However, isn't "where" used only to specify the values (cells) to be (or not to be) imputed but not the imputers? I want these cells not to be imputed but also not be used as imputers, and "where" only allows me to specify that I don't want these cells to be imputed. If I create a dataframe of logical values (TRUE/FALSE) to specify where imputations should occur, I still have some NAs for some cells I specified have to be imputed (I guess because some of my cells that I don't want to be used as imputers nor imputed are still being used as imputers and some of them are NAs).

Comment: You're right, `where` will avoid those cells from being imputed, not from being used as imputers. You can easily exclude certain columns from being used as imputers by altering the [predictor matrix](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/multiple-imputation.html#customizing-the-imputation-model-1), but I don't believe you can partially use a column as an imputer. Just to clarify, you want the UK cells to both **not be imputed** and **to be not used as imputers**, right? You will and should end up with some NA values if you don't want UK cells to be imputed.

Comment: Also, if you've used my code on your real data and you end up with NA values in places where values *should* be imputed, then please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your original question.